# Include directive with page variable doesn't work inside markup

Tags: php, markup, transclusion, pmwiki

I have some markup such as:

```
Markup('talk', '<include',
  '/\\(:talk:\\)/i',
  'MarkupTalk');
function MarkupTalk($m) {
  return 'Talk page: (:include {$BaseName}-talk:)'
}
```

but when I use it, it does nothing!

```
Example text (:talk:) more text
```

outputs

```
<div id="wikitext">
<p>Example text Talk page:  more text</p>
```

almost as if the `(:include:)` directive is a comment! It seems like `(:include:)` doesn't work when defined in other markup.

How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work properly is that your markup:

```
talk             <include         B>=><
```

is evaluated after one of its dependencies:

```
{$var}           >$[phrase]       B=>>
```

To fix this, you *could* change when your markup is evaluated:

```
Markup('talk', '<{$var}',
  '/\\(:talk:\\)/i',
  'MarkupTalk');
```

but this can be undesirable if you have any markup that outputs ("depends on") yours. Instead, you can modify your function to use the [`PageVar()`](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/Functions#PageVar) function as noted in [PmWiki.PageVariables](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/PageVariables), like so:

```
function MarkupTalk($m) {
  global $pagename;
  $pagename = ResolvePageName($pagename);
  return 'Talk page: (:include '. PageVar($pagename, '$BaseName') .'-talk:)'
}
```

This removes `{$var}` as a dependency and allows your markup to be safely evaluated after `{$var}` is.